# What's the proj4string for lambert conformal projection from this netcdf file

Tags: r, raster, projection, netcdf

*What I'm doing* I'm using R. I'm creating a raster from a NetCDF file. This is a weather forecast product from NAM model.

*What's the problem* I don't know how to specify the proj4string parameter when I create the SpatialPoints. For example, I'm looking for something like this:

```
+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
```

And I have the grid information at [grid description](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/docs/on388/tableb.html#GRID218). However, I don't know what do these parameters mean and how to match them up to `lat_0` and etc.

Therefore, to create the right projection information for the raster I created from the NetCDF file, how do I specify the projection for NetCDF?

The partial output from `print(nc_open('NAM_forecast.nc'))` is as follow:

```
float gridlat_0[xgrid_0,ygrid_0]   
            La1: 12.1899995803833
            Lo1: 226.541000366211
            Lov: 265
            Dx: 12.1909999847412
            Dy: 12.1909999847412
            Latin1: 25
            Latin2: 25
            units: degrees_north
            grid_type: Lambert Conformal (secant, tangent, conical or bipolar)
            long_name: latitude
            corners: 12.1899995803833
             corners: 14.3420877456665
             corners: 57.3284339904785
             corners: 54.5653381347656
float gridlon_0[xgrid_0,ygrid_0]   
            La1: 12.1899995803833
            Lo1: 226.541000366211
            Lov: 265
            Dx: 12.1909999847412
            Dy: 12.1909999847412
            Latin1: 25
            Latin2: 25
            units: degrees_east
            grid_type: Lambert Conformal (secant, tangent, conical or bipolar)
            long_name: longitude
            corners: -133.458999633789
             corners: -65.1255569458008
             corners: -49.4160041809082
             corners: -152.878616333008
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question since it looks like it didn't intrigue much interest.

I have created [a gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/Weiming-Hu/e7e8a2b3feb7f7305b9b4214018b2948) for solving the problem.